# Why do my hardrives change dev links?

Tags: hard-drive, devices, sata

With every boot my HDDs randomly change places, as in sometimes my root partition is on `sda`, while other times it books on `sdb`. Its really not bothersome as I use UUID for `fstab` and such, but its really just annoying. Does anybody know if there is a way to keep it from changing? I am using an IDE drive and a SATA drive.

Comment: Related: [How are /dev/sda and /dev/sdb chosen?](/q/371049/175814)

Answer (score 3):

The kernel gives no guarantee that these devices will retain the same device node names (ie, `sda`, `sdb`, etc) when the machine is booted. The names depend on the order in which the devices are discovered, which can be arbitrary.

This is exactly why we use the UUID and/or labels where possible. If you want to reference a specific disk, the symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-*` might be useful for you.

Comment: Yes, I already know that. But I would think there would be some waqy to help control which which id detected first, considering one is SATA and the other is IDE.

Comment: The important point here is that the order is arbitrary. The kernel probes for ATA (ie, SATA and IDE) devices _in parallel_ to reduce boot times. This means that there is no specified order. Is there a reason you don't want to use the symlinks?

Comment: No real specific reason, I just think it would be a little more orderly. I often use UUID. Thank you for your help.