# Getting Input/output error, External USB drive changes dev location, WHY?

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

I am using an external USB Drive and from time to time I get an `Input/output error` when trying to access the drive. I saw [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) and was trying to do the tests, I could do the short one successfuly (without errors) but the long one hangs.

I then tried to redo the test but `smartctl` couldn't find the `dev` so I did a `sudo fdisk -l` and here's where it gets interesting... The `dev` for the same drive had changed, I first found the drive in `/dev/sde` and then it was in `/dev/sdc`.

Why is this happening? What can I do to solve it?

**Update**: To clarify, my question is a little bit different from this one: [*Why do my hardrives change dev links?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177953/why-do-my-hardrives-change-dev-links) since my problem happens when the system is already booted (no reboot happens) and the dev location changes. Additionally the dev location change is accompanied with an error (see above).

**Update 2**: Apparently my problem is due to a faulty cable. When I move the external hard drive in a certain way I get the `Input/output error`. I am going to keep an eye on this issue, I will try another cable as soon as I can get one and then I will post an update.

***Tip***: If you're having an issue with your external hard drive, check the cable (See Update 2).

```
Device Info:
    Model Family:     Western Digital My Passport (USB, AF)
    Device Model:     WDC WD20NMVW-11AV3S0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do my hardrives change dev links?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/177953/why-do-my-hardrives-change-dev-links)

Comment: I think it's related but it's not actually the same since _Why do my hardrives change dev links?_ is about dev location on boot. My problem is that it happens with the system already booted.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it happens at boot or later. Whenever you add a new block device it's difficult to predict the associated kernel name and better to rely on symbolic links based on UUID, label, or ID depending on the case. When you (re-)connect an external drive there's a good chance it will have a different kernel name than the last time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will keep in mind to use dev with the UUID. However, I find it weird that this happens mid operation...

Comment: However, if the block device disappears or changes its name *while it is connected* the issue is a different one, since that shouldn't happen in the first place. Could you please include the output of `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` after the block device for the external drive vanishes or changes? Look for references to its former name (e. g. `sdc` or `sde`).

Comment: Exactly... why is this happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53412/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-loco-loop).

Comment: Apparently my problem was due to a faulty cable, I am still going to try to replicate the problem and I am going to try a new cable to see if it's actually the cause. I am updating the question to reflect this and possibly help somebody.

Comment: Thanks for the update. A faulty cable is a very plausible and likely cause for this kind of behaviour. However, we usually close questions that turn out to result from issues caused by hardware faults since Ubuntu has no influence on them which renders the question unrelated to Ubuntu and off topic.

Comment: I understand ...but when looking up the question in Google I didn't find anything like a cable related issue so it would be beneficial for someone with a similar issue. Don't you think?

Comment: Yes, it may be helpful but it's still off topic on AskUbuntu. If you really want to you can ask for your question to be migrated to [SU] where such issues are on topic. You can achieve that through a flag for moderator attention and a short note of your wish.